# Does your Visual Studio 2008 hang after installing Office 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, office-2010, incompatibility

Late night I installed Office 2010 Professional Plus. Here I am, the next morning, and Visual Studio 2008 is freezing, like there "was some invisible dialog window", because it doesn't allow me to click on any IDE element.

In brief, after I open an ASP.NET MVC form, suddenly I'm not allowed to click on anything, icon, dock panel, toolbox, nothing. Weird....

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140308014234/http://geekswithblogs.net/hinshelm/archive/2009/07/19/office-2010-gotcha-2-visual-studio-2008-locks.aspx)

You need to run a repair on the “Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component” that is part of Office 2007.